# overlapping CIDR range between VPC Peering - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have an VPC with an CIDR range `10.10.0.0/16` and another VPC in different region with a CIDR range `10.11.0.0/16`.

1. Are these two considered overlapping? When i tried to connect these two VPC through VPC-Peering, it
   was not working. I changed the CIDR range for second VPC to
   `172.16.0.0/16` and it connected.
2. Is there a way to debug in such situations?

Comment: Are you talking about VPC peering?

Comment: @jellycsc: Yes, VPC Peering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CIDR block `10.10.0.0/16` contains the IP addresses `10.10.0.1` to `10.10.255.254`.

The CIDR block `10.11.0.0/16` contains the IP addresses `10.11.0.1` to
`10.11.255.254`.

Those IP ranges do not overlap. It would have been helpful to see the actual error message reported when you tried to peer those VPCs to diagnose your issue further.

---

You can search for "CIDR Calculator" to find lots of websites that will help you with these calculations so you don't have to ask here and wait for someone to do the calculation for you.

Comment: Thanks Mark, this helps... How do i see an actual error message? In terminal when i try to ping.. it does not work.. just keeps on hanging.